# I want to make nothing selected when I set selectbox to disable

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu

There is an input form to enter numbers and a Selectbox to select its unit.
I want to make it impossible to select a unit when no number is entered, and to clear the value of the Selectbox when the number is erased after the unit is selected.

```
<div>
   <input-number v-model="number" />
   <select v-model="unit" :disabled="!form.model.number">
     <select-option v-for="item in currency_unit">
          {{ item.name }}
     </select-option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add a **:key** directive every time you iterate something.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input number v-model="number" />
    <select v-model="unit" :disabled="!number">
      <option v-for="item in currency_unit" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

To clear the **unit** value you can use *watcher*

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Component',
  data() {
    return {
      number: '',
      unit: null,
      currency_unit: [
        { name: 'foo', id: 1 },
        { name: 'bar', id: 2 },
      ],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    number(newValue) {
      if (!newValue) {
        this.unit = null;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the disable condition to be `number === ''` and set the initial value of `number` as `''`

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
    number: '',
    unit: null,
    currency_unit: [
     { id: 'rupee', name: 'Rupees'},
     { id: 'dollar', name: 'Dollars'},
     { id: 'euro', name: 'Euros'}
    ]
  };
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input number v-model="number" />
    <select v-model="unit" :disabled="number===''">
      <option v-for="item in currency_unit" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, You can put a `watcher` on `number` model value. So that if it gets empty you can assign an empty or null value to `unit`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: null,
    unit: null,
    currency_unit: [{
      name: 'A'
    }, {
      name: 'B'
    }, {
      name: 'C'
    }]
  },
  watch: {
    number(val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.unit = null;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="number" />
  <select v-model="unit" :disabled="!number">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in currency_unit" :key="index">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```